# How to load images faster, smoother, and without OutOfMenory error?

Tags: android, android-gridview

i am trying to write a media player application. In this i have to load album art(s) from a network to GridView of android. With my initial implementation, it's working fine, but it's not fast, not smooth. Loading images(.jpeg) taking more time. I have resize the images to low resolution, even now not working. In my observation, Saavn(android application) loading album arts very fastly.
How can i load my album arts with that speed in more efficient way.
I have gone through http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/faster-loading-images-in-gridviews-or-listviews-in-android-using-menory-caching/
but not helpful. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought to use Image loading libraries?

Try to use [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup) library, its good.

Comment: Everything is already on the link. it is very easy. just read it.

Comment: Is it possible to load images from LAN( smbFile ) with this lib?

Answer (score 1):

Try this image loading library.

[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Sample code is availabe [Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Easy to integrate.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Can i use this lib to load images from LAN( SmbFile path )?

Comment: I don't know much about the LAN(Smb File). but whatever the format is you can convert that format in the URI. i,e. the Physical path where the image is present, then Picasso will able to show it. If I helped you, Accept my answer

Comment: Yup... this is good. It's loading very fast and easy to integrate and very smooth scrolling. But my images are in LAN( SmbFile ).I can upvote your answer. Thanks.